# Problems with changing the size of the two upper boxes ( text/image)

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my website responsive and for mobile and iPad it seems to work pretty well but for desktop I have a problem. I'm trying to figure out how to expand the two upper boxes (image and text). My website looks like this right now:

[image: My website]

But the result should look like the picture to the left:
[image: Responsive design]

Here is my HTML for the two upper boxes:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&family=Montserrat:wght@100&family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300;700&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2f2f0;
}


/* Header  */

header {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #d0c8b6;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.title {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
}

.logo {
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 40px;
}


/*  The bigger news   */

nav {
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav div {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-box {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0%;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* The other news   */

.flex-parent1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-parent2 {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.image {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  display: inline;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 350px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.footer-text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.date {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.image {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.image1 {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* Mobile */

@media (min-width: 668px) {
  header {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  nav {
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .headertext {
    display: none;
  }
  .title {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .logo {
    position: absolute;
  }
}


/* Desktop */

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  header {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  nav {
    width: 60%;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
  .logo {
    position: static;
  }
  .headertext {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent1">

  <div class="child1">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5581939/pexels-photo-5581939.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="image1" />
  </div>

  <div class="child2">
    <p class="text">Tourism is travelling for pleasure or to enjoy yourself away from the place you live. People do this for many different reasons – to have fun, visit other countries and learn about other cultures or just relax from stressful working life. Tourists
      go to various destinations, countries with great landmarks, places with lovely beaches or simply areas of wilderness and untouched nature. In the last few decades tourism has grown very much, mostly because people’s lifestyles have changed. They
      don’t want to stay at home any more. They spend more money on travelling than previous generations did. Travelling has also become cheaper and more affordable. The rise of budget airlines has made it possible to afford trips to faraway countries.
      Tourism is travelling for pleasure or to enjoy yourself away from the place you live. People do this for many different reasons – to have fun, visit other countries and learn about other cultures or just relax from stressful working life. he rise
      of budget airlines has made it possible to afford trips to faraway countries. about other cultures or just relax from stressful working life. he rise of budget airlines has made it possible to.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "expand" you mean put them in a row for larger screens, just set the flex direction to `row` by default, and you already have it overridden for mobile.

View this demo in fullscreen mode and resize.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&family=Montserrat:wght@100&family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300;700&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2f2f0;
}


/* Header  */

header {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #d0c8b6;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.title {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
}

.logo {
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 40px;
}


/*  The bigger news   */

nav {
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav div {
  width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-box {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0%;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* The other news   */

.flex-parent1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-parent2 {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.image {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  display: inline;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 350px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.footer-text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.date {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.image {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.image1 {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* Mobile */

@media (min-width: 668px) {
  header {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  nav {
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .headertext {
    display: none;
  }
  .title {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .logo {
    position: absolute;
  }
}


/* Desktop */

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  header {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  nav {
    width: 60%;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
  .logo {
    position: static;
  }
  .headertext {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent1">
  <div class="child1">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5581939/pexels-photo-5581939.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="image1" />
  </div>

  <div class="child2">
    <p class="text">Tourism is travelling for pleasure or to enjoy yourself away from the place you live. People do this for many different reasons – to have fun, visit other countries and learn about other cultures or just relax from stressful working life. Tourists
      go to various destinations, countries with great landmarks, places with lovely beaches or simply areas of wilderness and untouched nature. In the last few decades tourism has grown very much, mostly because people’s lifestyles have changed. They
      don’t want to stay at home any more. They spend more money on travelling than previous generations did. Travelling has also become cheaper and more affordable. The rise of budget airlines has made it possible to afford trips to faraway countries.
      Tourism is travelling for pleasure or to enjoy yourself away from the place you live. People do this for many different reasons – to have fun, visit other countries and learn about other cultures or just relax from stressful working life. he rise
      of budget airlines has made it possible to afford trips to faraway countries. about other cultures or just relax from stressful working life. he rise of budget airlines has made it possible to.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```